# Sizing Logos in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am putting together a flyer for our company. We have three different logos. The logos are actually trademarked or registered names such as ReMan, LiftTrax, LiftSafe and all are in the same font. When I import them, they are all different sizes.
I need all the three of these logos to be the same size for placement purposes. How do I get all three of these logos to be the same size?
Thank you.

Comment: In most cases, it's more about visual adjustment than technically being the *exact* same size. Some logos will just naturally appear to take up more space than others. So, generally adjusting by *eye* is better than trying to measure things.

Answer (score 1):

When you place the image in InDesign, you'll notice it's placed inside an Image Frame.

[image]

To resize the image *and* the frame, you need to hold down CMD + SHIFT and then click on one of the corners to resize it.

Alternatively, after clicking on the Image Frame, you can enable Auto-Fit, at the top menu bar.  This will resize the image to fit the frame automatically, so you only need to hold SHIFT while resizing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the files you're placing need to adjusted in the authoring program (Photoshop, Illustrator etc) to make the files the exact size you want, and then place them. Or you can adjust them in InDesign by selecting the content (SHIFT + ESC) and then typing in the exact proportions you want in the control bar, then fitting the frame to the content (though the suggestions above work too). If they're going to be placed over and over, it might be a better idea to make the files themselves all the exact sizes you want in the authoring program itself.